# Is there special syntax needed when using browserify with mustache?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, watchify

I am using browserify with gulp and I am having problems with loading my templates. What is strange, my paths are correct as far as I can tell, but my templates don't load.

This is my directory structure:

[image: directory structure]

This is my app.js file:

```
$(function() {
    var EventUtility = {

        //EventUtilityCode
    };


    var flimFlam = document.getElementById('flimFlam');


    function templateLoader(e) {
        var doc = document,
            body = doc.getElementsByTagName('body'),
            overlay = $('#overlay');
        $.Mustache.load('../templates/index.html')
            .done(function() {
                $('body').mustache('templateID');
            });

        $('body').prepend(overlay);

    }

    EventUtility.addHandler(flimFlam, 'click', templateLoade
```

r);

And this is my template:

```
<script id="templateID" type="text/html">
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="container" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="twelve columns">
                   <div class="modal-container">
                        <div id="modal" class="modal-animation">
                            <p>This app will go through some of your markup to determmine if it could be more accessible.  We will start by checking the alt tags on your images, seeing if they exist, or if the tags are empty!<br>
                            <a id="appButton" class="button button-primary modal-button">lets get started!</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**
Does anyone think I should be using this `module.exports = function () {}` to get my mustache libs to work? Is that it? But that is not needed for the other libraries (e.g. jquery, mixitup). So i guess that's grasping straws?

Comment: what is the Mustache for?

Comment: @dandavis To add a template.

Comment: well that's not a Mustache tempalte, it's just html, so the plain $.load should work. that said, i think you just need to change the path. the path to JS is not the path of the js file (like it is in php), it's the path of the page, so you likely want `$.Mustache.load('/templates/index.html')` or `$.Mustache.load('templates/index.html')`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.